# Redirect .html to /

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

We are looking for a solution to redirect our .html pages to pages with a / so for example:

old:

```
www.domain.com/url.html
```

New:

```
www.domain.com/url/
```

We found the following method to delete the .html, this only does not place a / on the end:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

So with the following method you delete the .html but there is not a / placed on the end. Is there a way to replace the .html with a /?

Hope someone can help

Comment: so what is the problem? since you found the method for doing it ?

Comment: So what exactly is your problem?

Comment: Just tried to make it more clear in the question. This is not the solution, with that method you don't replace the .html with a / you only delete the .html so the url will look lik: www.domain.com/url and it should become www.domain.com/url/

Answer (score 1):

Try below rule,

```
RewriteEngine On

#redirecting to extension less url with forward slash

RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1/ [R=301,L]

#handling the extension less url

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.html [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the pages you want to redirect:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/" />
```